# Error al acceder listado de entradas

Tags: wordpress

me pasa una cosa muy rara, solo con mi usuario, soy administrador, cuando entro en el listado de Entradas me devuelve el error de WordPress de error critico, solo me pasa con el listado de Entradas y con mi usuario, a los otros administradores no les pasa, alguien sabe a que puede ser debido????

Comment: Y el código, que aparece en el error log, estas usando código personalizado?, la información que das no sirve ya que tendríamos que adivinar que pasa para ayudarte, por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour], tampoco estaría de mas leer como hacer un [example].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.